# Url canonicalization issue

Tags: php, url

In my website like http://www.someone.com. I have a wallpaper section as

```
http://www.someone.com/wallpaper/ 
http://www.someone.com/wallpaper/index.php?imageid=123
```

I have read some articles on it, (Url canonicalization). 
I want to know that-------could it be harmful to my site search. 
I am worried about it because site search is not growing and google is not showing the description of the index page as I gave to the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A canonical page/url is the preferred version of a set of pages/urls with highly similar content. So basically you are telling search engines such as google that the indicated site in the link attribute is the main site.

Im not sure whether those two are the same or similar webpages as you have not indicated, but if they are, they might have produced different urls due to the fact that the image wallpaper might of have been used to list several pages with the same list of products or content i.e the first page url displays your wallpaper from the top level keyword and the second url shows the same wall paper from a specified category,

If Google knows that these pages have the same content, they index only one version for othe search results, the one in ewhich you have indicated as the most usefl for search engine users.

Ankit you shouldnt worry about the description for the index page, it will show; but if you wish to prevent this from happening again in the near future, ensure you write SEO friendly URLS, have unique content and add a robots meta tag which includes a no index and a no follow.

All the best